# How to create a Playlist using the Nokia Music API?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nokia

I'm just starting playing with the Nokia Music API and it seems straightfoward to use. However, I would like to know if is possible to create a Playlist using the API.

I mean, I want to create different playlist. For example, one for running, one for work, and so on.

Is it possible with the API? Or should it be implemented in a different way?

Any help would be very appreciate

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the mixRadio API you are refering, i.e. the one you can access from: http://developer.nokia.com/lumia/nokia-apis/music

Then, the API is using the MIXES for playing, thus you can not make playlists as such with it, but indeed you could pre-select your mix to be used in different situations, and then have a log for launching the right mix when needed.